# Install multiple versions of an info manual

Tags: info, automake, autotools

I have GNU Guile 2.2.6 installed on my system as `guile`, and GNU Guile 3.0.5 installed as `guile3`. I would like to install the info manuals for both versions. Both want to install the info files as `/usr/share/info/guile.info{,-1,-2,..}`, so whichever I install last overwrites the manual for the other version. How can I keep both versions? Version 2.2.6 is provided by my package manager, and I'm currently building version 3.0.5 like this:

```bsh
./configure --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=3
make
sudo make install
```

Ideally `info guile` would bring up the documentation for version 2.2.6, while `info guile3` would show the docs for version 3.0.5.

Comment: Instead of using `--prefix=/usr`, try `--prefix=/usr/local`. At least the files won't overwrite each other if you can't change the name during the build/install processes.

Comment: I'm packaging this for the Arch user repository, so I unfortunately can't put it in `/usr/local`.